# Business process templates/models in S/4HANA

Tags: abap, s4hana

I am trying to understand what is currently the "way to go" for Business process templates creation in S/4, cloud and on-premise. Actually, I am not even sure that the naming ("templates") is the correct one as of today, maybe it should be called "Business process models" or somehow else.

Anyway, there is a nice picture in https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_POWERDESIGNER/5cf5d195c910456fb4b080f9f6219c6d/c81214036e1b10148328f73d31fed981.html?version=16.6.9
[image]

I hope, I understand it correct that there are business objects behind the boxes in the picture like "book flight" or "book hotel" ?

So, if using Powerdesigner, is it possible to generate an ABAP code after such a diagram has been created as above? Can Powerdesigner be used with S/4 ?

Here another docu speaks about process templates in S/4
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_ON-PREMISE/6d52de87aa0d4fb6a90924720a5b0549/9a5211544e901b5de10000000a44538d.html?locale=en-US
This are processes for master data management only, not for other "parts" of S/4, right?

Is [Workflow Managment](https://help.sap.com/docs/workflow-management/sap-workflow-management/model-process-templates) able to create workflows that can be consumed in S/4 or is it a completely separate tool?

There are also business workflows in S/4

- https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_S4HANA_ON-PREMISE/0f18dddf28764f5b807ecd80549044cc/550e6b573f4a0222e10000000a44147b.html
- https://blogs.sap.com/2019/08/15/workflow-in-s4hana-public-cloud-and-on-premise/

Are they related to the Workflow Management tool above or there are completely separated tools ?